# SETX set environment variables from a file

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to set some environment variables that are specified in a file.
Using `setx` works fine for one environment at a time, but how can I pipe a file with the below contents

```
FOO bar
BAR foo
```

I was thinking something like this

```
setx < cat envvars.txt
```

but of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `Foreach-Object` loop to start `SETX` along with the current item within the loop.

An example:

```
Get-Content c:\file.txt | Foreach-Object {SETX [Options] $_}
```

We get the contents of a file, c:\file.txt, and for every item use `SETX`

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to powershell and this helped a lot. Have a great day

Comment: Happy to help, one thing is note worthy PowerShell can start programs and pass an ArguementList to them.  Try `Get-Help Start-Process -Full`  as an example: `Start-Process "D:\Program Files (x86)\TreeSize Professional\tsizepro.exe" -ArgumentList "\\$server\$drive$"` starts TreeSize pro with two parameters ServerName and DriveLetter

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to the accepted answer if you created file.txt using:

`SET >> file.txt`

`Get-Content file.txt | Foreach-Object {SETX $_.split("=")}`